# Inverse PHP mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

Inverse PHP `mysql_fetch_array`

I get last 4 row from database, but I want order these 4 rows in inverse

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a lot easier to use correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4) t ORDER BY id ASC");
```

i Think this should do

Comment: I think the OP wants the last 4 as he already has, but wants them ordered ASC instead of DESC. This returns an entirely different rowset.

Comment: please do not use `mysql_*`

Comment: Thx Bhadra, why use `t` before ORDER ?

Comment: You have to assign a variable to the query.